# Next.js font doesn't work in _document.tsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js 13.
I'm trying to apply a font in `_document.tsx` but the font isn't applied.

I'm using local font like below.

```js
import localFont from 'next/font/local';

export const notoSansKR = localFont({
  src: './NotoSansKRVariable.woff2',
});
```

- `_document.tsx`

```js
        <body className={notoSansKR.className}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
```

However when I use it in layout component which is rendered from `_app.tsx`, it works.

- `_app.tsx`

```js
            <Layout>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Layout>
```

- components/layout/index.tsx

```js
  <div className={notoSansKR.className}>{children}</div>;
```

I'm curious what is the matter in `_document.tsx`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the font in _app.tsx instead of _document.tsx.
I remember getting an eslint error when adding mine in _document.

Remove the class name from `<body className={notoSansKR.className}>` and add it to your top most element in app.tsx. If you only have providers etc you can just wrap them in a `div` or `main`.

And also, you have all your pages in `/pages` folder right? Because the method you have used will not apply fonts to pages in the `/app` folder